# Project clean before each export with proguard

Tags: android, proguard

I'm having some very strange behavior using proguard.  Here is the situation.

In eclipse if I just run the export command I get the below errors. Along with many `can't find referenced class` errors.  Also the number 241 below seems to jump around, sometimes its 179, 290, and etc.

```
[2012-05-22 15:54:33 - x] Warning: there were 241 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2012-05-22 15:54:33 - x]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2012-05-22 15:54:33 - x] Warning: there were 36 unresolved references to program class members.
[2012-05-22 15:54:33 - x]          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
[2012-05-22 15:54:33 - x]          You may need to recompile them and try again.
[2012-05-22 15:54:33 - x]          Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
[2012-05-22 15:54:33 - x]          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
[2012-05-22 15:54:33 - x] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2012-05-22 15:54:33 - x]   at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2012-05-22 15:54:33 - x]   at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2012-05-22 15:54:33 - x]   at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2012-05-22 15:54:33 - x]   at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

But if I do a clean and then export it will not show an error, but also not show any console output at all.  This first export after clean will produce a file that runs.  If I try doing an export immediately after the previous export it will fail with the above errors again.

Additional Info -

> My workspace path and git repo paths both have no spaces in them.
>
> My proguard.cfg file is mostly the default one provided by android/eclipse, with just a few extra 'keep's' added
>
> I had an old workspace setup with my project and I can successfully export using proguard (this project uses SVN through subclipse on OS X).
>
> I copied the project to the current workspace and hooked it up to GIT using egit.  Egit moved the files out of my workspace and into the location of the git repo.

TL;DR; What would make proguard run successfully after a clean but fail every time its run without cleaning first?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17988163/1318946